# How to partial mock objects of the same class twice in OCMock 3.4.2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ocmock

```
EKSource *source1 = [[EKSource alloc] init];
EKSource *source2 = [[EKSource alloc] init];

id source1Mock = OCMPartialMock(source1);
[[[source1Mock stub] andReturnValue:@(EKSourceTypeBirthdays)] sourceType];

id source2Mock = OCMPartialMock(source2);
[[[source2Mock stub] andReturnValue:@(EKSourceTypeCalDAV)] sourceType];

NSLog([source1 sourceType]); # Getting EKSourceTypeLocal instead of EKSourceTypeBirthdays
NSLog([source2 sourceType]); # Getting EKSourceTypeCalDAV. Expected behaviour.
```

I'm trying to partial mock two objects of EKSource class as shown above. After mocking source2 object, source1Mock stops mocking. How to solve this problem ? I did not notice this issue in OCMock 3.4.1.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in OCMock 3.4.3 release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is correct. There's a [bug](https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/issues/357) in version 3.4.1 of OCMock. The bug was fixed in version 3.4.3 - see [release notes](https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/blob/master/Source/Changes.txt).

I suggest using macros to stub methods because they are much more intuitive to write and easier to read.

e.g. `OCMock([source1 sourceType]).andReturn(@(EKSourceTypeBirthdays))`